# How do I split this array object?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and trying to troubleshoot some legacy code.

```
echo " **** REQ: ".$requirement.PHP_EOL;
echo " **** REQ ##: ".get_object_vars($requirement).PHP_EOL;
$myArray=explode(",",$requirement);
print_r($myArray);
```

The output of this gives me:

```
**** REQ: Requirement=[equipment,N]
**** REQ: Array
Array
(
    [0] => Requirement=[equipment
    [1] => N]
)
```

I would like to be able to save the values within the hard brackets. So that `x` = `equipment`, and `y` = `N`. I appreciate any help.

Comment: or you could use regex for that too (another alternative  if you want), get the string inside the square brackets, if its always two then add it inside the pattern as well, it not, then you can incorporate the explode

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly but if you give me example of how you want array look like I think I can help you

Comment: Where is the code behind `$requirement`, can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to get the text between `[` and `]` then do an explode on `,`

```
<?php

$raw = "Requirement=[equipment,N]";
$requirement = '';

echo " **** REQ: ".$raw.PHP_EOL;

preg_match('#\[(.*?)\]#', $raw, $requirement);

$myArray=explode(",",$requirement[1]);

print_r($myArray);
```

Output:

```
**** REQ: Requirement=[equipment,N] 
Array 
( 
    [0] => equipment 
    [1] => N 
)
```

Comment: Why not capture the words one by one with the regex? You first use regex which is a very powerful parser then switch to a "low end" parser to finnish it off. Why?

Comment: I'm not that well-versed in regex

Answer (score -1):

You can eval the string.
If the string comes from a user do not use this method since eval can cause harm to your system.
It's basically giving the user access to your code. Kind off...
But if it's from a 'secure source' then this works but with a notice.

```
$str = "Requirement=[equipment,N]";
Eval("$" . $str . ";");

Var_dump($Requirement);
```

https://3v4l.org/2dBrd